# Android app widget with aspect ratio layout

Tags: android, widget

Hi want to make app widget with resizable square layout (1:1 aspect ration)

So I am able to provide the initial size with android:targetCellWidth="1" and android:targetCellHeight="1" but user can resize the widget like 2X1, I want to allow only 1x1, 2x2, 3x3... sized widgets. How can I do that?

I see that ConstraintLayout is capable to do that but unfortunately this is not supported in windgets. Also I treid to customize FrameLayout but still customozid layouts also not supported in widgets.